# Is it better to use a boolean variable to replace an if condition for readability or not?

Tags: variables, if-statement, boolean, conditional-statements, conventions

I am in the second year of my bachelor study in information technology. Last year in one of my courses they taught me to write clean code so other programmers have an easier time working with your code. I learned a lot about writing clean code from a video ("clean code") on pluralsight (paid website for learning which my school uses). There was an example in there about assigning if conditions to boolean variables and using them to enhance readability. In my course today my teacher told me it's very bad code because it decreases performance (in bigger programs) due to increased tests being executed. I was wondering now whether I should continue using boolean variables for readability or not use them for performance. I will illustrate in an example (I am using python code for this example):

- example boolean variable

Let's say we need to check whether somebody is legal to drink alcohol we get the persons age and we know the legal drinking age is 21.

```
    is_old_enough = persons_age >= legal_drinking_age
    if is_old_enough:
        do something
```

My teacher told me today that this would be very bad for performance since 2 tests are performed first persons_age >= legal_drinking_age is tested and secondly in the if another test occurs whether the person is_old_enough.
My teacher told me that I should just put the condition in the if, but in the video they said that code should be read like natural language to make it clear for other programmers. I was wondering now which would be the better coding practice.

- example condition in if:

  ```
  if persons_age >= legal_drinking_age:
      do something
  ```

In this example only 1 test is tested whether persons_age >= legal_drinking_age. According to my teacher this is better code.

Thank you in advance!

yours faithfully

Jonas

Comment: "`My teacher told me today that this would be very bad for performance since 2 tests are performed first persons_age >= legal_drinking_age is tested and secondly in the if another test occurs whether the person is_old_enough`". Except its exactly the same if you use a separate variable, and they'll potentially even be optimized to the same code anyways. If they're not optimized to the same code, the only difference would be that the boolean variable may stay in memory a little longer. Use the separate variable if you find it helps readability.

Comment: If you were doing this comparison in multiple places, and the values of `persons_age` and `legal_drinking_age` don't change, I'd think that using a boolean variable would be efficient than doing the comparison again and again.

Comment: If you're writing in a compiled language, the compiler can figure out how best to optimize this sort of thing. Generally, it's best to write something that is easy to read and comprehend.

Comment: Even if not using the intermediate variable *did* do less checks, both `>=`  and a check for truthiness are so fast you'd be hard pressed to find a scenario where such a change would make even a measurable difference; let alone a significant one. As stated, I have to disagree with you teacher entirely. Do what's the most readable, and worry about performance when it actually becomes a problem.

Comment: Always do as your teacher asks you to. After getting the grade - do whatever you want.

Answer (score 1):

> I was wondering now which would be the better coding practice.

The real safe answer is : Depends..

I hate to use this answer, but you won't be asking unless you have faithful doubt. (:

IMHO:

If the code will be used for long-term use, where maintainability is important, then a clearly readable code is preferred.

If the program speed performance crucial, then any code operation that use less resource (smaller dataSize/dataType /less loop needed to achieve the same thing/ optimized task sequencing/maximize cpu task per clock cycle/ reduced data re-loading cycle) is better. (example keyword : space-for-time code)

If the program minimizing memory usage is crucial, then any code operation that use less storage and memory resource to complete its operation (which may take more cpu cycle/loop for the same task) is better. (example: small devices that have limited data storage/RAM)

If you are in a race, then you may what to code as short as possible, (even if it may  take a slightly longer cpu time later). example : Hackathon

If you are programming to teach a team of student/friend something.. Then readable code + a lot of comment is definitely preferred .

If it is me.. I'll stick to anything closest to assembly language as possible (as much control on the bit manipulation) for backend development. and anything closest to mathematica-like code (less code, max output, don't really care how much cpu/memory resource is needed) for frontend development.  ( :

So.. If it is you.. you may have your own requirement/preference.. from the user/outsiders/customers point of view.. it is just a working/notWorking program. YOur definition of good program may defer from others.. but this shouldn't stop us to be flexible in the coding style/method.

Happy exploring. Hope it helps.. in any way possible.

Answer (score 1):

**Performance**

Performance is one of the least interesting concerns for this question, and I say this as one working in very performance-critical areas like image processing and raytracing who believes in effective micro-optimizations (but my ideas of effective micro-optimization would be things like improving memory access patterns and memory layouts for cache efficiency, not eliminating temporary variables out of fear that your compiler or interpreter might allocate additional registers and/or utilize additional instructions).

The reason it's not so interesting is, because, as pointed out in the comments, any decent optimizing compiler is going to treat those two you wrote as equivalent by the time it finishes optimizing the intermediate representation and generates the final results of the instruction selection/register allocation to produce the final output (machine code). And if you aren't using a decent optimizing compiler, then this sort of microscopic efficiency is probably the last thing you should be worrying about either way.

**Variable Scopes**

With performance aside, the only concern I'd have with this convention, and I think it's generally a good one to apply liberally, is for languages that don't have a concept of a named constant to distinguish it from a variable.

In those cases, the more variables you introduce to a *meaty* function, the more intellectual overhead it can have as the number of variables with a relatively wide scope increases, and that can translate to practical burdens in maintenance and debugging in extreme cases. If you imagine a case like this:

```
some_variable = ...
...
some_other_variable = ...
...
yet_another_variable = ...
(300 lines more code to the function)
```

... in some function, and you're trying to debug it, then those variables combined with the monstrous size of the function starts to multiply the difficulty of trying to figure out what went wrong. That's a practical concern I've encountered when debugging codebases spanning millions of lines of code written by all sorts of people (including those no longer on the team) where it's not so fun to look at the locals watch window in a debugger and see two pages worth of variables in some monstrous function that appears to be doing something incorrectly (or in one of the functions it calls).

But that's only an issue when it's combined with questionable programming practices like writing functions that span hundreds or thousands of lines of code. In those cases it will often improve everything just focusing on making reasonable-sized functions that perform one clear logical operation and don't have more than one side effect (or none ideally if the function can be programmed as a pure function). If you design your functions reasonably then I wouldn't worry about this at all and favor whatever is readable and easiest to comprehend at a glance and maybe even what is most writable and "pliable" (to make changes to the function easier if you anticipate a future need).

**A Pragmatic View on Variable Scopes**

So I think a lot of programming concepts can be understood to some degree by just understanding the need to narrow variable scopes. People say avoid global variables like the plague. We can go into issues with how that shared state can interfere with multithreading and how it makes programs difficult to change and debug, but you can understand a lot of the problems just through the desire to narrow variable scopes. If you have a codebase which spans a hundred thousand lines of code, then a global variable is going to have the scope of a hundred thousands of lines of code for both access and modification, and crudely speaking a hundred thousand ways to go wrong.

At the same time that pragmatic sort of view will find it pointless to make a one-shot program which only spans 100 lines of code with no future need for extension avoid global variables like the plague, since a global here is only going to have 100 lines worth of scope, so to speak. Meanwhile even someone who avoids those like the plague in all contexts might still write a class with member variables (including some superfluous ones for "convenience") whose implementation spans 8,000 lines of code, at which point those variables have a much wider scope than even the global variable in the former example, and this realization could drive someone to design smaller classes and/or reduce the number of superfluous member variables to include as part of the state management for the class (which can also translate to simplified multithreading and all the similar types of benefits of avoiding global variables in some non-trivial codebase).

And finally it'll tend to tempt you to write smaller functions as well, since a variable towards the top of some function spanning 500 lines of code is going to also have a fairly wide scope. So anyway, my only concern when you do this is to not let the scope of those temporary, local variables get too wide. And if they do, then the general answer is not necessarily to avoid those variables but to narrow their scope.